# How to show only the data which are not empty in mat-table

Tags: angular-material, angular8

How to show only data object which are not empty in response JSON?

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<ng-container matColumnDef="type">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Type </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.type}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="version">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Version </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.version}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="number">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Number </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.version}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="part">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Part </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.part}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Description </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

Please find the below sample JSON response and attached the screenshot of the data table.

```
{"items":[{"description": "Test 12345","part":"P1","type":"AB","version":"V1.0","number":"12345"},{},{},{"description": "Test 67890","part":"P1","type":"XY","version":"V2.1","number":"67890"}]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Table is rendered correct because you have 2 empty objects in response.
If You want to get rid of them just simply iterate over data array and check if there is empty object.

```
const yourResponse = [{}, {id: 1}, {}, {id: 2}, {}];

const filteredArray = yourResponse.filter(element => {
  if (Object.keys(element).length !== 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
});

// [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
console.log(filteredArray);
```

This way you will avoid having empty rows in table.